# CSS- how to correctly implement dropdown menu go sideways?

Tags: css

I want dropdown effect to go sidways.

I am able to do that with `display: inline-table` effect. **1) is there a better way to do this??**

though above works, it expands content on the right side of parent component( `dropbtn` in this case). You can refer to below code how this uglyfies layout.
I want to make it span towards left side of parent button so that the button stays at its current position. 2) Is there a way to hack it?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btn {
      background-color: #37abc8ff;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-table;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: inline-table;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="btn">Hello</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

strong text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way is to put the `.dropdown-content` div before `.dropbtn` button in your HTML structure:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #37abc8ff;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-table;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-table;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Hello</button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  </div>
</div>
```